# sytemctl -> Failed to look up unit file state: Invalid argument

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

### SETUP

I have a simple script: script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;do
    echo "$(date)"
    sleep 3
done
```

And I want to keep it running by including it in a service unit for systemd. So I create a simple unit file: unit

```
[Unit]
Description=test

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/user/p/test/system/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I then create a symbolic link in /etc/systemd/system to the unit file and give it a unique name

```
ln -s $(readlink -f ./unit) /etc/systemd/system/superspecial.service
```

Now I can start the service

```
systemctl start superspecial
```

And it works. I of course cannot see the echo, but I can see it in

```
systemctl status superspecial
```

### PROBLEM

Sweet, now my problem:
When I want to 'enable' the service, so that it starts on boot, I get a cryptic error message and searching for that message was unsuccessful.

```
€ systemctl enable superspecial.service
Failed to look up unit file state: Invalid argument
```

What argument? What is the state of a unit file?
Is there something missing in my unitfile?
Some info on my system:

```
€ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
€ systemctl --version
systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.16)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

Some info about the running service:

```
€ systemctl status superspecial
● superspecial.service - test
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/superspecial.service; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-04-27 15:58:01 CEST; 14min ago
   Main PID: 13111 (bash)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 9282)
     Memory: 540.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/superspecial.service
             ├─13111 /bin/bash /home/user/p/test/system/script.sh
             └─20421 sleep 3

Apr 27 16:11:45 hostname bash[13111]: Mi 27. Apr 16:11:45 CEST 2022
Apr 27 16:11:48 hostname bash[13111]: Mi 27. Apr 16:11:48 CEST 2022
Apr 27 16:11:51 hostname bash[13111]: Mi 27. Apr 16:11:51 CEST 2022
Apr 27 16:11:54 hostname bash[13111]: Mi 27. Apr 16:11:54 CEST 2022
Apr 27 16:11:57 hostname bash[13111]: Mi 27. Apr 16:11:57 CEST 2022
```

I of course tried running with root privileges, rebooting and restarting the service over and over.
Maybe it has something to do with the 'bad' in the systemctl status?

Comment: Why do you make your service as a symlink? Is there a specific reason to not just put the file in /etc/systemd/system/ ?
My gut feeling is telling me that enable does not like a unit to be a symlink

Comment: Second question would be: Why do you create your symlink in such a convoluted way? I mean, why make a readlink? why especially readlink -f ? are there even more symlinks? if so, why?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I tried that command

```shell
sudo ln -s /home/username/myproject/config/systemd.conf /etc/systemd/system/myproject.service
```

and had the same problem. Then tried that command:

```shell
sudo ln -f /home/username/myproject/config/systemd.conf /etc/systemd/system/myproject.service
```

I used `-f` instead of `-s`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. You were right. Using a hardlink instead of a symlink fixed it.
`readlink -f` is just what I use if I want the absolute path to a file entry.